# How to updated a table (accessed in pandas) in DuckDB Database?

Tags: python, pandas, duckdb

I'm working on one of use case, I have a larger volumes of records created in a duckdb database table, these tables can be accessed in pandas dataframe, do the data manipulations and send them back to DB table. here below I will explain my case.

1. I have a DB called as MY_DB in Duck DB and a table in it as ROLL_TABLE_A, here it will be queried and converted as a Pandas data frame as _DF.
2. The same table (ROLL_TABLE_A) can be accessed by multiple users and do the required updates on the data frame _DF.
3. How to upload the data frame _DF into the same table ROLL_TABLE_A?.

Steps to reproduce:

```
# Connection and cursor creations
dbas_db_con = duckdb.connect('MY_DB.db')
```

```
# list of DB TABLE
dbas_db_con.execute("SHOW TABLES").df()
```

[image]

```
# Query on DB Table
dbas_db_con.execute("SELECT *FROM ROLL_TABLE_A").df()
```

[image]

```
# convert database table to pandas table
_df = dbas_db_con.execute("SELECT *FROM ROLL_TABLE_A").df()
```

Here on _df id field is filled up with multiple user and after updating pandas dataframe it will be as.

[image]

Here the updated dataframe to be updated in ROLL_TABLE_A Table in DuckDB.

```
dbas_db_con.execute("SELECT *FROM ROLL_TABLE_A").df()
```

On accessing a ROLL_TABLE_A it will produce an output as

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that takes a dataframe, table name and database path as input and writes the dataframe to the table:

```
def df_to_duckdb(df:pd.DataFrame, table:str, db_path:str):
    con = duckdb.connect(database=db_path, read_only=False)
    
    # register the df in the database so it can be queried
    con.register("df", df)
    
    query = f"create or replace table {table} as select * from df"
    con.execute(f"{query}")

    con.close()
```

The part that took me a while to figure out is registering the df as a relation (e.g. table/view) in the database. Registering does not write the df to the database, but is essentially a pointer within the database that references the df in memory.